# Set counter in a figure in a subsection

Tags: floats

I have a figure in a subsection of my thesis that is continued to the next page. The figure is numbers as Figure 5.2. When it continues to the next page Latex sets the number as 5.3. I tried to change the numbering of the figure with \setcounter{figure}{5.2} but I could not do it. Does anyone know what I can do?

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! Maybe `\addtocounter{figure}{-1}` before entering the 2nd figure environment?

Comment: you have not given much information (as the default figure environment does not allow page breaking) but add -1 as Bernard suggests, or use `\setcounter{figure}{2}`  not 5.2  before the second `\caption`.

Comment: Could you please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that shows how you split the figure onto two pages? Probably `continuedfloat` is also helpful.